# Как проверить простое ли число Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, простые-числа

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать функцию `is_prime`, принимающую **`1`** аргумент — число от **`0`** до **`1000`**, 
и возвращающую `True`, если оно простое, и `False` - иначе."

```
def is_prime(a):
    if a % a == 0 and a != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(is_prime(a))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так :

```
def is_prime(a):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return a == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= a and a % d != 0:
        d += 2
    return d * d > a

print(is_prime(int(input("Enter a number: "))))
```

---

```
print( [ '{} - True'.format(i) for i in range(2, 1001)  if is_prime(i)])
```

Comment: При `a = 1` неправильно.

Answer (score 3):

Оптимизированный алгоритм поиска простых неотрицательных чисел:

1. проверить на 0 и 1
2. проверить на чётность и равенство 2 (исключается ~50% чисел)
3. проверить на кратность 3 и равенство 3 (исключается ещё ~33% чисел)
4. для проверки оставшихся чисел воспользоваться формулой `6n ± 1` (при n = 1, простыми будут 5 и 7, при n = 2: 11 и 13, и т.д.)
5. как отмечено раньше, проверять делители следует до корня из заданного числа

код:

```py
def is_prime(num):
    prime = num > 1 and (num % 2 != 0 or num == 2) and (num % 3 != 0 or num == 3)
    i = 5;
    d = 2;

    while prime and i * i <= num:
        prime = num % i != 0
        i += d
        d = 6 - d # чередование прироста 2 и 4: 5 + 2, 7 + 4, 11 + 2, и т.д.
    return prime
```

Тест:

```
print(*[ i for i in range(101) if is_prime(i)]) 
>> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 2):

- Простое число — натуральное (целое положительное) число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя — единицу и самого себя.

Будем проходить по циклу до корня числа, ведь если мы не найдём делитель до корня данного числа, то дальше нет смысла искать, не найдём делители.

---

Вот работающий код:

```
def is_prime(a):
    if a < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(a ** 0.5 + 1)):
        if a % i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True
print(is_prime(int(input())))
```

Comment: Зачем вы добавляете ответы во все старые вопросы? В данном случае ответ хуже уже имеющегося.

Comment: В том ответе допущена ошибка - в  коде выше 1 является простым числом, а также отрицательные числа тоже являются простыми. Но это же не так!

Comment: Ну этот код тоже не супер, мягко говоря

Comment: @Эникейщик, но почему? Он выполняет поставленную задачу.

Comment: Потому что делает намного больше вычислений, чем нужно. А так то можно и умножение сложением в цикле выполнять, тоже выполняет задачу.

Comment: @Эникейщик, но главная цель - решить задачу.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я подправил код, теперь хорошо.

Comment: `В том ответе допущена ошибка` - о недочёте можно подсказать в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

Вот моё решение:

```
def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2, (x//2)+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Оно простое, лакониченое и оптимизированное. Цикл перебирает возможные делители числа от двойки до **половины** проверяемого числа, ибо проверять числа дальше просто нет смысла, так как любое лисло нацело делится максимум на половину себя.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Посмотрите на код получше, если введём 0, то вывод будет True, попробуйте доработать код.

Comment: да и до половины проверять нет смысла. Так же нет смысла проверять на четные числа, после проверки на 2

Answer (score 2):

эффективнее перебирать числа до корня соответствующего числа

```
def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, int(number ** 0.5) + 1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]