# поиск простых чисел на python

Tags: python

помогите плис решить задачу на пайтон. допустим есть лист с числами  мне нужно найти простые числа и создать с ними новый лист.
входные данные `lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`
выходные данные `res = [0,2,3,5,7,11]`

```
def prime(n):
    res = []
    k = 0
    for i in n:
        l = i
        for k in range(2, l // 2 + 1):
            if (l % k == 0):
                k = k + 1
        if (k <= 0):
            res.append(l)
    return res
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что в res забыл 0? Мало того, что он не простой, так его и в исходном списке не было.

Comment: Ноль не простое число. Простое число имеет ровно два натуральных делителя. Ноль имеет бесконечное число делителей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправляешь `is_prime` из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1040164/178988) (надо добавить проверку на 1) и делаешь

```
res = [x for x in lst if is_prime(x)]
```

Comment: почему-то при выводе получается так: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11] 1 же не являетсяпростым числом и мне еще нужно чтобы был выведен 0

Comment: @VsevolodPravdin, с единицей косяк - добавь if.