# Не получается написать функцию поиска всех простых чисел на отрезке

Tags: python

Мне нужно написать функцию поиска всех простых чисел на отрезке

я написал такой код, но он неправильный, и не могу понять как написать правильно, помогите пожалуйста, что исправить, чтобы работало:

```
def min_from_four(a,b,c,d):
    if a <= b and a <= c and a <= d:
        return a
    elif b <= a and b <= c and b <= d:
        return b
    elif c <= a and c <= b and c <= d:
        return c
    else:
        return d

def aaa(number):
    if number == 2:
        return "yes"
    elif number == 3:
        return "yes"
    else:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if number % i == 0:
                return "no"
        return "yes"

print(aaa(6))
```

Comment: а где именно тут отрезок то? что мешает вашу функцию `aaa` прогнать по отрезку?

Comment: Вся первая функция заменяется на min(a,b,c,d). Зачем она, кстати,  вообще в вопросе присутствует?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить простое ли число Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040160/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-python-3)

Answer (score -1):

```
def aaa(num):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            count += 1

    return 'yes' if count == 2 else 'no'
```

Вроде это то что вам нужно

Comment: Это совершенно точно не то, что нужно. Что эта функция вообще делает?

Comment: Как я понял, данная функция определяет является ли число простым.

Comment: Аа, ахаха, я понял вашу замысловатую логику, пардон. Действительно, определяет простое ли число. Правда, это самый дурацкий способ, который я видел.