# Сумма всех простых чисел меньше заданного числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Решая задачу, я столкнулся с трудностью. Вот данные задачи:

> Напишите функцию, которая находит сумму всех простых чисел меньше заданного числа n. Простое число - это число, которое делится только на себя и на 1.

А вот мой код:

```py
def sum_of_primes(n):
    primes = []
    for num in range(2, n):
        if is_prime(num):
            primes.append(num)
    return sum(primes)

def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2, int(num ** 0.5)):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

В этом коде функция `sum_of_primes()` должна находить сумму всех простых чисел меньше **n**. Она использует вспомогательную функцию `is_prime()`, которая проверяет, является ли число простым.

Буду очень благодарен, если вы мне объясните, где тут моя ошибка, и в чем?

Comment: Мы уже разобрались в функциях. Дай вопросу заголовок, который отражает твою конкретную проблему.

Comment: В чем твоя ошибка можешь разобраться сам, проверив свою функцию на числах от 1 до 10 хотя бы. Элементарные навыки отладки нужно уметь!

Comment: См. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1367476/386633) на вопрос: [Как проверить простое ли число Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040160/). Реализация функции `is_prime` в принятом ответе как минимум некорректна для входных 0 и 1.  Также она будет проверять подряд все делители числа, даже если оно чётное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка заключается в том, что вы неправильно реализовали функцию `is_prime()`. Проверьте, например, число "4". Ваша функция скажет, что это простое число. Хотя, очевидно, это не так.

Для корректного подсчёта используйте данную функцию:

```
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Обратите внимание на крайние значения `range()`. Подробнее о работе последовательностей можно прочитать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges).

Comment: огромное спасибо, что осветители на мой вопрос и дали источник для дальнейшего обучение!

Comment: Добавлю, что в функции `sum_of_primes()` вам необязательно помещать все найденные простые числа в список. Вы можете просто инициализировать переменную (изначально равняется нулю)  для накопления суммы найденных чисел. Так вы сэкономите память.

Comment: Не надо `int(n**0.5)`. Используйте `math.isqrt`.