# Написать функцию, определяющую количество простых чисел во входном списке целых чисел

Tags: python

Написать функцию определяющую кол-во простых чисел в списке целых.

Список передаётся в качестве параметра, полученный результат возвращается из функции.

```py
def num_1(*args):
    count = 0
    for num in args:
        if num < 2:
            continue
        else:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if num % i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                count += 1
    return count


print(num_1(10))
```

Выводит не тот ответ

Comment: Почему вы решили, что ваш код нерабочий?  В представленном примере, входной список содержит одно число 10, которое НЕ является простым и соответственно выводится 0.

Answer (score 0):

Определите отдельную функцию `is_prime` для проверки, является ли число простым (оптимизированный пример можно найти [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1367476/386633)), и вызывайте её для каждого входного аргумента своей функции:

```py
def num_1(*args):
    count = 0
    
    for num in args:
        if is_prime(num):
            count += 1
    return count

def is_prime(num):
    prime = num > 1 and (num % 2 != 0 or num == 2) and (num % 3 != 0 or num == 3)
    i = 5;
    d = 2;

    while prime and i * i <= num:
        prime = num % i != 0
        i += d
        d = 6 - d # чередование прироста 2 и 4: 5 + 2, 7 + 4, 11 + 2, и т.д.
    return prime

print(num_1(-2, 2, 3, 5, 10))
```

Результат:

```
3
```