# Нужно оптимизировать программу, которая проверяет числа в диапазоне m и n на простоту

Tags: python, оптимизация, простые-числа

Time limit: *0.5 сек*.

```
def is_simple(a):
for j in range(2, int(a ** 0.5) + 1):
    if a % j == 0:
        return False
return True


m, n = map(int, input().split())
arr = []
for i in range(m, n + 1):
    if is_simple(i):
        arr.append(i)
if len(arr) == 0:
    print('Absent')
else:
    print(*arr, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Ну, задача стара как мир. Дубликатов должно быть море.

Comment: Если простых чисел нет в диапазоне m и n. Нужно вывести "Absent"

Comment: Если вы хотите что-либо добавить к своему вопросу, не нужно писать это в комментариях. Дополнить вопрос можно нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Да поищите тут поиском, тут тьма таких задач разбирается. Но вообще если `n` и `m` произвольные, то не сильно то много тут получится ускорить.

Comment: Какие ограничения на *m* и *n*? Какие ограничения на память?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить простое ли число Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040160/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-python-3)

Comment: @NowhereMan, проверка простоты одного числа и группы последовательных чисел - очень разные задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Сегментированное решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE):

```
import math


def primes_in_range(n1, n2):

    def primes_in_range(n1, n2):
        sieve = [True] * (n2 - n1)

        def cross_out(p):
            for i in range((-n1) % p, n2 - n1, p):
                sieve[i] = False

        if 2 < math.isqrt(n2 - 1) + 1:
            cross_out(2)
        for p in range(3, math.isqrt(n2 - 1) + 1, 2):
            cross_out(p)
        return (n1 + i for i, v in enumerate(sieve) if v)

    n1 = max(n1, 2)
    while n1 < n2:
        n = min(n1 ** 2, n2)
        yield from primes_in_range(n1, n)
        n1 = n


def main():
    for p in primes_in_range(*map(int, input().split())):
        print(p)


main()
```

Решето хранится для полуинтервала *[n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>)*. `cross_out(p)` вычеркивает из решета все числа кратные *p*. Из-за особенностей решения нужно чтобы было *n<sub>2</sub> ≤ n<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>*. Если полуинтервал больше, он обрабатывается в несколько приемов.

Что можно успеть за полсекунды:

> ```
> $ time echo 1 1_350_000 | python segmented-sieve-0.py > temp_0.txt
>
> real  0m0.479s
> user  0m0.480s
> sys   0m0.000s
>
> $ time echo 1_000_000_000 1_001_000_000 | python segmented-sieve-0.py > temp_0.txt
>
> real  0m0.496s
> user  0m0.484s
> sys   0m0.008s
>
> $ time echo 1_000_000_000_000 1_000_000_500_000 | python segmented-sieve-0.py > temp_0.txt
>
> real  0m0.494s
> user  0m0.488s
> sys   0m0.008s
> ```

Потребление памяти можно снизить в восемь раз, если заменить обычный список на `bytearray`. Скорость тоже вырастет немного:

```
def primes_in_range(n1, n2):

    def primes_in_range(n1, n2):
        sieve = bytearray(n2 - n1)

        def cross_out(p):
            for i in range((-n1) % p, n2 - n1, p):
                sieve[i] = 1

        if 2 < math.isqrt(n2 - 1) + 1:
            cross_out(2)
        for p in range(3, math.isqrt(n2 - 1) + 1, 2):
            cross_out(p)
        return (n1 + i for i, v in enumerate(sieve) if v == 0)

    n1 = max(n1, 2)
    while n1 < n2:
        n = min(n1 ** 2, n2)
        yield from primes_in_range(n1, n)
        n1 = n
```

В решете можно не хранить флаги для чётных чисел. Потребление памяти снизится ещё в два раза. Скорость вырастет примерно в два раза. Код станет даже проще в каком-то смысле:

```
def primes_in_range(n1, n2):

    def primes_in_range(n1, n2):
        sieve = bytearray((n2 - n1) // 2)
        for p in range(3, math.isqrt(n2 - 1) + 1, 2):
            for i in range(((p - n1) // 2) % p, (n2 - n1) // 2, p):
                sieve[i] = 1
        return (n1 + 2 * i for i, v in enumerate(sieve) if v == 0)

    if n1 <= 2 < n2:
        yield 2
   
    n1 = max(n1 + 1 - n1 % 2, 3)
    n2 += 1 - n2 % 2
    while n1 < n2:
        n = min(n1 ** 2, n2)
        yield from primes_in_range(n1, n)
        n1 = n
```

Что можно успеть за полсекунды:

> ```
> $ time echo 1 3_600_000 | python segmented-sieve-2.py > temp_2.txt
>
> real  0m0.489s
> user  0m0.480s
> sys   0m0.008s
>
> $ time echo 1_000_000_000 1_003_200_000 | python segmented-sieve-2.py > temp_2.txt
>
> real  0m0.496s
> user  0m0.488s
> sys   0m0.004s
>
> $ time echo 1_000_000_000_000 1_000_001_300_000 | python segmented-sieve-2.py > temp_2.txt
>
> real  0m0.499s
> user  0m0.492s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
p = list(range(m + 1))
p[1] = 0
i = 2
while i <= m:
    if p[i] != 0:
        j = i + i
        while j <= m:
            p[j] = 0
            j = j + i
    i += 1
res=[i for i in p if i != 0 and i >= n]
print(res) if res else print("Absent")
```

Comment: А, ну "решето Эратосфена", конечно, оптимально. Правда, так и неизвестно, какие в задачке `m` и `n`, если они вдруг очень большие, но близкие друг к другу, решето не будет оптимальным.