# Не могу понять алгоритм определения число простое или нет

Tags: javascript

```js
simpleNum:
for (let i = 2; i < 50; i++) {
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) continue simpleNum;
    }

    console.log(i);
}
```

Задача была вывести простые число от 1 до 50 и за 2 часа у меня так и не получилось решить задачу. Я полез в интернет и нашел такое решение, но я немного не понимаю алгоритм действий в этом решении. Разъясните пожалуйста

Comment: А что именно непонятного? Тривиальный алгоритм без каких либо оптимизаций…

Comment: Единственное что может вызвать вопросы это метка для continue. Вот https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for#metki-dlya-break-continue

Comment: Мне немного непонята последовательность действий. Я просто не до конца могу понять, алгоритм действий, когда у меня цикл в цикле. Я не пойму, у меня i и j сразу инкрементируются или нет.

Comment: Где-нибудь перед if сделайте что-то вроде `console.log(i, j);` и увидите что в каком порядке инкрементируется

Comment: Я понимаю, что решение легкое, но я просто не понимаю последовательность действий.

Answer (score -16, accepted):

Цикл for i выполняет цикл j, потом цикл i++ выполняет цикл j и т.д.

Comment: 10 раз перечитал ответ, не понимаю, о чём он. Отредактируйте ответ, добавьте деталей.

Comment: @aepot, главное, что автору вопроса ответ понравился )

Answer (score 8):

Перед тем как начать рассматривать алгоритм, рассмотрим саму проблему

Что такое простое число?

> Простое число — натуральное число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя. Другими словами, натуральное число `p` является простым, если оно отлично от `1` и делится без остатка только на `1` и на само `p`
>
> [Источник: Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)

По началу понять число простое или нет достаточно просто, например `2, 3, 5, 7` и т.д.

А вот `137` простое число или нет? Уже не так очевидно... А если взять число `1298754829483`? Значит нам явно нужен алгоритм для определения число простое или нет

Самый простой способ - это перебрать абсолютно все числа от `2` до заданного числа (**не** включительно) и проверять делится ли нацело заданное число на проверочное число? Если делится, значит число **не** простое, т.к. нашёлся делитель помимо `1` и самого числа

Почему от `2`? - Потому что на `1` нацело делится любое натуральное число, и потому в лишний раз проверять на его делимость не имеет смысла

Почему до заданного числа (**не** включительно)? - На само число проверять нет смысла, т.к. любое натуральное число нацело делится на самого себя, а на большие числа тем более нет смысла, т.к. если натуральное число поделить на большие натуральные числа, то мы будем получать числа между `0` и `1`

Напишем такой функционал:

```js
const isPrime = num => {
  if (num === 1) return false;
  
  for (let i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
    if ((num % i) === 0) return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(1, 'is prime: ', isPrime(1));
console.log(2, 'is prime: ', isPrime(2));
console.log(3, 'is prime: ', isPrime(3));
console.log(4, 'is prime: ', isPrime(4));
console.log(5, 'is prime: ', isPrime(5));
console.log(6, 'is prime: ', isPrime(6));
console.log(7, 'is prime: ', isPrime(7));
console.log(8, 'is prime: ', isPrime(8));
console.log(9, 'is prime: ', isPrime(9));
console.log(137, 'is prime: ', isPrime(137));
console.log(1298754829483, 'is prime: ', isPrime(1298754829483));
```

P.S. Проверка на единицу нужна, потому что `1` единственное натуральное число, которое не является ни [составным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) ни простым

У вас есть диапазон чисел от `1` до `50`, а значит мы можем просто пройтись по нему циклом и для каждого числа вызывать `isPrime`

```js
const isPrime = num => {
  if (num === 1) return false;
  
  for (let i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
    if ((num % i) === 0) return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

for(let i = 1; i < 50; ++i) {
  if (isPrime(i)) console.log(i);
}
```

В целом это всё что вам нужно. Но теперь вернёмся к синтаксису, который вы нашли.

Перепишем то что у нас уже есть на похожий синтаксис:

```
checkNum: for(let i = 1; i < 50; ++i) {
  if (i === 1) continue;
  
  for (let j = 2; j < i; ++j) {
    if ((i % j) === 0) continue checkNum;
  }
  
  console.log(i);
}
```

По сути я просто перенёс функцию внутрь цикла. Но теперь у нас появились [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue). Они играют роль `return`, который был у нас в функции. Как `return` может досрочно остановить выполнение функции, так и `continue` приостанавливает текущую итерацию цикла, в котором находится, но если мы хотим чтобы `continue` останавливал текущию итерацию родительского цикла, то нам нужны [метки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Т.к. мы заранее знаем, что `1` - это не простое число, то можем его убрать как из верхнего цикла (и начать с `2`) так и саму провекру на единицу:

```js
checkNum: for(let i = 2; i < 50; ++i) {
  for (let j = 2; j < i; ++j) {
    if ((i % j) === 0) continue checkNum;
  }
  
  console.log(i);
}
```

Что ровно то же самое что и у вас, с мелкими изменениями:

```
simpleNum:
for (let i = 2; i < 50; i++) {
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) continue simpleNum;
    }

    console.log(i);
}
```

Надеюсь теперь стало понятнее :)

## Доп. материал (оптимизация)

Наш алгоритм, котрый мы рассматривали выше, можно очень сильно оптимизировать

Давайте представим входное число `k` как произведение двух чисел, тогда `k = n * m`. Думаю это очевидно что чем больше `n` тем меньше `m` и наоброт. Отсюда вытекает, что должен быть момент, когда `n` и `m` уровнятся. А когда же это произойдёт?

```
k = n * m; n = m;

k = n * n

k = n ^ 2

n = ±sqrt(k)

s = sqrt(k);

n = ±s

n ∈ N

n = s
```

И так мы выяснили что `n` и `m` встретятся когда оба будут равны квадратному корню от входного числа `k` (`s`). Отсюда следует, что проверять деление на числа после `s` не имеет смысла, следовательно ограничиваем наши проверки этим числом и тогда количество операций для определения явялется ли число простым сильно сокращается. Сделаем эксперимент:

```js
const isPrimeWithOpt = num => {
  let steps = 1;
  if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};
  
  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); ++i) {
    ++steps;
    
    if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
  }
  
  return {steps, result: true};
}

const isPrimeWithoutOpt = num => {
  let steps = 1;
  if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};
  
  for (let i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
    ++steps;
    
    if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
  }
  
  return {steps, result: true};
}

const testDatas = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  137,
  7919,
  2147483647,
  1298754829483
];

for (const testData of testDatas) {
  const {result: result1, steps: steps1} = isPrimeWithOpt(testData);
  const {result: result2, steps: steps2} = isPrimeWithoutOpt(testData);
  
  console.log(testData, 'is prime with/without optimization:', result1, '/', result2);
  console.log('Steps with/without optimization:', steps1, '/', steps2);
  console.log('==============================');
}
```

Где мы видим, что если число не простое, то количество операций бывает одинаковым, но если число простое, то мы пропускаем огромное количество лишних итераций

### Двигаемся дальше (Спасибо [avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp))

> Если в оптимизации не останавливаться на sqrt, то легко заметить, если число не делится на 2, то на остальные четные делить не надо. Таким образом надо идти в цикле от 3 до sqrt через 2 (т.е. проверять только нечетные)

Действительно! Зачем проверять делимость числа на `4, 6, 8, ... 2n` если ещё в самом начале мы можем выяснить делится ли число на `2` или нет?

Почему мы имеем право так делать? - Потому что, единственным чётным простым числом является `2`, а значит можно смело говорить, что число **не** простое, если оно делится на `2` и не равен `2`-ум. Либо дргуими словами - все простые числа кроме `2` - нечётные, а значит если у числа нет делителя `2`, то искать делители вида `2n` не имеет смысла, потому что если бы они были, то сама `2`-ка обязательно должна была бы быть в списке делителей числа, т.к. сами числа вида `2n` делятся на `2`

Как же нам пропускать все чётные делители? Элементарно, вместо `++i` писать `i += 2` и начинать цикл не с `2`, а с `3`, получится `3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ... 2n + 1`

С учётом вышесказанного можем программу переписать и снова провести эксперимент

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const isPrime = num => {
    let steps = 1;
    if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};

    for (let i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
      ++steps;

      if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
    }

    return {steps, result: true};
  }

  const isPrimeOpt = num => {
    let steps = 1;
    if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};

    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); ++i) {
      ++steps;

      if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
    }

    return {steps, result: true};
  }

  const isPrimeOpt2 = num => {
    let steps = 1;
    if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};

    ++steps;
    if ((num % 2) === 0) return {steps, result: num === 2};
    /*
      if ((num % 2) === 0) {
        if (num === 2) return {steps, result: true};
        else return {steps, result: false};
      }
    */

    for (let i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2) {
      ++steps;

      if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
    }

    return {steps, result: true};
  }

  const testDatas = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    137,
    7919,
    2147483647,
    1298754829483
  ];

  for (const testData of testDatas) {
    const {result: result1, steps: steps1} = isPrime(testData);
    const {result: result2, steps: steps2} = isPrimeOpt(testData);
    const {result: result3, steps: steps3} = isPrimeOpt2(testData);

    console.log(testData, 'is prime (method 1 / 2 / 3):', result1, '/', result2, '/', result3);
    console.log('Steps (method 1 / 2 / 3):', steps1, '/', steps2, '/', steps3);
    console.log('==============================');
  }
  
  document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'none';
}, 16)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.loading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.spinner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}


.text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
  <span class="text">Calculating... Please wait!</span>
</div>
```

Этот подход ускоряет подбор делителей практически в `2` раза по сравнению с перебором всех чисел с шагом в `1`

### Двигаемся дальше (Спасибо [Nowhere Man](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/386633/nowhere-man))

> аналогично можно отбросить числа кратные трём и проверять только числа, отвечающие формуле `6n ± 1`, как указано в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040160/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-python-3/1367476#1367476) на [аналогичный вопрос на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040160/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-python-3)

Действительно, если взять например первую сотку чисел начиная с `1` и убрать все числа кратные `2`-ум и `3`-ём, то легко заметить, что начиная с `5` все числа выражаются формулой `6n ± 1`, где `n ∈ N`

Давайте докажем это утверждение:

```
-- ДОКАЗАТЕЛЬСТВО ОТ ОБРАТНОГО --

Пусть `k` - некое число из полуинтервала `[5, ∞)`, которое не удовлетворяет формуле `6n ± 1`, где `n ∈ N`

Это число не может быть чётным, т.к. по условию мы убрали все числа, кратные `2`-ум =>
это число нечётное =>
оно выражается формулой `2m + 1`, где `m > 1 и m ∈ N`

Но, не забываем, что мы так же исключили все числа кратные `3`-ём =>
`2m + 1 ≠ 3j`, где `j - нечётное, j > 1 и j ∈ N` =>
`j = 2i + 1`, где `i ∈ N` =>
`2m + 1 ≠ 3(2i + 1)` =>
`2m + 1 ≠ 6i + 3` =>
`2m ≠ 6i + 2` =>
`m ≠ 3i + 1` =>
Я могу взять абсолютно любой `m`, который не удовлетворяет формуле `3i + 1` =>
Я имею право взять формулу `3i` для `m` =>
`2m + 1 = 2(3i) + 1 = 6i + 1`, а теперь заменив `i` на `n` получаем `6n + 1`

Проделав всё то же самое только для `2m - 1`, где `m > 2 и m ∈ N`, мы получим `6n - 1`

И так мы пришли к противоречию с изначальным утверждением, т.к. получили что любое натуральное
число после исключения чисел кратных `2`-ум и `3`-ём в полуинтервале `[5, ∞)` можно выразить
либо как `6n + 1` либо как `6n - 1`
```

С учётом вышесказанного можем программу переписать и снова провести эксперимент

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const isPrime = num => {
    let steps = 1;
    if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};

    for (let i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
      ++steps;

      if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
    }

    return {steps, result: true};
  }

  const isPrimeOpt = num => {
    let steps = 1;
    if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};

    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); ++i) {
      ++steps;

      if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
    }

    return {steps, result: true};
  }

  const isPrimeOpt2 = num => {
    let steps = 1;
    if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};

    ++steps;
    if ((num % 2) === 0) return {steps, result: num === 2};
    /*
      if ((num % 2) === 0) {
        if (num === 2) return {steps, result: true};
        else return {steps, result: false};
      }
    */

    for (let i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2) {
      ++steps;

      if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
    }

    return {steps, result: true};
  }
  
  const isPrimeOpt3 = num => {
    let steps = 1;
    if (num === 1) return {steps, result: false};

    ++steps;
    if ((num % 2) === 0) return {steps, result: num === 2};
    /*
      if ((num % 2) === 0) {
        if (num === 2) return {steps, result: true};
        else return {steps, result: false};
      }
    */
    
    ++steps;
    if ((num % 3) === 0) return {steps, result: num === 3};

    let isLittleStep = false;

    for (let i = 5; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += isLittleStep ? 2 : 4) {
      ++steps;

      if ((num % i) === 0) return {steps, result: false};
      
      isLittleStep = !isLittleStep;
    }

    return {steps, result: true};
  }

  const testDatas = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    137,
    7919,
    2147483647,
    1298754829483
  ];

  for (const testData of testDatas) {
    const {result: result1, steps: steps1} = isPrime(testData);
    const {result: result2, steps: steps2} = isPrimeOpt(testData);
    const {result: result3, steps: steps3} = isPrimeOpt2(testData);
    const {result: result4, steps: steps4} = isPrimeOpt3(testData);

    console.log(testData, 'is prime (method 1 / 2 / 3 / 4):', result1, '/', result2, '/', result3, '/', result4);
    console.log('Steps (method 1 / 2 / 3 / 4):', steps1, '/', steps2, '/', steps3, '/', steps4);
    console.log('==============================');
  }
  
  document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'none';
}, 16)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.loading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.spinner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}


.text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
  <span class="text">Calculating... Please wait!</span>
</div>
```

Этот подход ускоряет подбор делителей практически ещё на `33%` по сравнению с перебором только нечётных чисел

> Также статья на хабре про разные быстрые методы поиска простых чисел (C#): [Ищем простые числа до триллиона за тридцать минут (2020)](https://habr.com/ru/articles/526924/)

Comment: Если в оптимизации не останавливаться на sqrt, то легко заметить,  если число не делится на 2, то на остальные четные делить не надо. Таким образом надо идти в цикле от 3 до sqrt через 2 (т.е. проверять только нечетные)

Comment: @avp Прекрасное замечание, спасибо! Постараюсь завтра добавить это тоже

Comment: @avp Готово, можете проверять!)

Comment: @EzioMercer, аналогично можно отбросить числа кратные трём и проверять только числа, отвечающие формуле `6n ± 1`, как указано в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1367476/386633) на [аналогичный вопрос на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040160/).  Также статья на хабре про разные быстрые методы поиска простых чисел (C#): [Ищем простые числа до триллиона за тридцать минут (2020)](https://habr.com/ru/articles/526924/)

Comment: @NowhereMan Я уже об этом думал, просто уже не стал писать, потому что насколько я понял, в широком понимании, нужно отбрасывать и всё что делится на 5, на 7, на 9 и т.д. для всех простых чисел. Или я неправильно уловил суть этих оптимизаций?

Comment: Не совсем правильно.  Отбросив чётные числа и кратные трём, для проверки останется всего-навсего ~17% в диапазоне до `√(n)`.  А пары 5 и 7, 11 и 13, 17 и 19, и много других описываются формулой `6n ± 1`.  То есть, к примеру, для 137 будет проверено всего навсего 3 числа - 5, 7, и 11.

Comment: @NowhereMan Понял, спасибо за разъяснене! Обязательно добавлю ваше замечание тоже, как будет время

Comment: @NowhereMan Готово, можете проверять!)

Comment: Тогда уж нужно обобщить все оптимизации до [wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization), добавить решето, совместить решето с wheel factorization, перейти к сегментированному решету.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо большое за ваше предложение! Но боюсь я пока не готов, очень подробно расписывать более комплексные алгоритмы. Если хотите, можете предоставить ссылку(и) на подробные объяснения и я с радостью включу их в свой ответ, как это сделал с предоставленной статьёй из хабра ранее