Возвращать массив простых чисел из заданного промежутка
Задача
Сделайте функцию, которая будет возвращать массив простых чисел из заданного промежутка
Решение


function res(min, max) {
  let arr = []

  function isPrime(n) {
    for (let i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
      if (n % i === 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function printPrimes(min, max) {
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i = i + 2) {
      if (isPrime(i)) console.log(i)
    }
  }
  printPrimes(min, max);
}
console.log(res(11, 31))



Вопрос
Не могу понять откуда как добавить в массив и откуда undefined при выводе

не зная как работать с массивом или как работает функция, пытаешся решить задачу? тут вся база с примерами: https://learn.javascript.ru/ думаю после изучения сам найдеш ответ.

Не могу понять откуда как добавить в массив - Вот прямо так и пишите в гугле. Пишите "как добавить в массив JavaScript", посмотрите.

откуда undefined при выводе - А почему не должно быть undefined? Что вы писали, чтобы функция вернула не undefined?

undefined - потому что функция ничего не возвращает. У вас нет наполнения массива. Скорее всего должно быть так if (isPrime(i)) arr.push(i). Ну и в конце функции res должно быть return arr

@Armen  Да я уже пофиксил. Затупил знатно, но поправил. И ведь реально полез в учебник. Пожалуй хватит на сегодня программирования) Чувствую себя персонажем басни Крылова. Спасибо, что ткнули носом.

@alexWithoutBeard если будет что то не понятное во время изучения, буду рад помочь, приятного отдыха.



function res(min, max) {
  let arr = []

  function isPrime(n) {
    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
      if (n % i === 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function printPrimes(min, max) {
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i = i + 1) {
      if (isPrime(i)) arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  printPrimes(min, max);
  return arr
}

console.log(res(1, 31))




Почемы вы пропускаете 2-ку? Вам так же может помочь мой ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1563524/385375

@EzioMercer Поправил. Спасибо, что указали на недочёт.
